# event.preventdefault() not working on change event of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here exactly I am trying to make my textbox to accept only numbers. I am able to detect keyCode but event.preventdefault() is not working.

**complete html + javascript**

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#textbox1").keydown(function(event) {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
                        {
                            alert("valid number");
                        }   
                        else
                        {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            alert("It's NAN");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(ex) {
                        alert('An error occurred and I need to write some code to handle this!');
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM>
            <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRz8g/).

How do I achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event to intercept the change.

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DKFhe/)**

Comment: Use `event.which` for compatibility with FF. See updated fiddle.

Comment: it's working fine, but can you please tell why keypress not keydown? what's the problem caused by keydown?

Comment: Not really. There has been [variations](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) of the spec and why this event currently is the one leading to key insertion is a little unclear to me, especially regarding the third event keyup. But today `keypress` seems to be considered by all browsers as the consequence of other raw key actions and so the one really being the key insertion.

Answer (score 0):

As @dystroy said, you should change your keydown to keypress and you should delete the                  `event.preventDefault();` near the end (the second one) to make the code work.

[JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cRz8g/3/)

Comment: What do you mean? Look at the original code that it has two preventDefault . One in else and one near the end. I said remove the preventDefault that was near the end